# .htacces redirect folder links to index.php routing page

Tags: .htaccess, routes, directory

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have some `<a>` links that are equal to folder names. E.g.

```
www.mysite.com/test/scripts/ is a folder path
<a href="/test/scripts/"> is the link
```

Now my problem is that if a link points to a folder, I get the `403 - Forbidden` error.
How can I modify my `.htaccess` in order to redirect links that are matching folders to the `index.php` page, which is a routing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by addind a `!`. This because if the URL is NOT a folder it mantains this URL, else it redirects all to index.php.

Complete code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```